# Total percent of Union query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the percentage of the different classes for each month, each class is taken from a separate base (person1, person2 and person3) knowing that the three bases contain the same class names. and that I want the total percentage in union of the three bases. I tried to do this, but got different percentages from the true values I have.

```
select 100*count(distinct person)/max(all_1) as percent_1,class,bb.month from (select * from  person_1) aa inner join (select count (person) as all_1, month from person_1 group by month) bb on aa.month = bb.month group by class,bb.month 
 
union select 100*count(distinct person)/max(all_2) as percent_2,class,bb.month from (select * from  person_2) aa inner join (select count (person) as all_2, month from person_2 group by month)bb on aa.month = bb.month group by class,bb.month 

union select 100*count(distinct person)/max(all_3) as percent_3,class,bb.month from (select * from  person_3) aa inner join (select count (person) as all_3, month from person_3 group by month)bb on aa.month = bb.month group by class,bb.month
```

Example: (month 1)
**Base person_1**

| class | person |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Anis |
| 1 | Amir |
| 2 | Tata |
| 3 | Toto |
| 3 | Titi |
| 3 | Mimi |

**Base person_2**

| class | person |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BABA |
| 1 | Bibo |
| 1 | Asya |
| 2 | KIWI |
| 3 | Kita |
| 3 | amal |

the result I want to have is the percent:

| Month | Class | nbr | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 42% |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 16% |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 42% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT class, COUNT(*) nbr, 100 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () percent
FROM ( SELECT class
       FROM person_1
     UNION ALL
       SELECT class
       FROM person_2 ) total
GROUP BY class
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1fd72ad110bda6f081601ca1dec57ef)